# How can I trigger azure service bus subscription from URL or azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I want to use a service bus as a webhook

according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-batch I can access the service using post request but I need to add an authentication which is not possible for the webhook I'm using

I thought I could add an intermediate layer using azure function, so basically the azure function is the webhook and it forwards the message to the service bus but I can't include Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus in azure function so I can't do that as well

Is there a way simple way I can forward the message to the service bus?

Comment: What do you mean by "Trigger azure service bus subscription"? Do you want to add a message to a Service Bus topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add with Andrés Nava - .NET**

If you are not using precompiled azure function and you want to reference the external assemblies,you could use  **#r "AssemblyName"**. we could get more information from [Azure Functions C# script developer reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)

> The following assemblies may be referenced by simple-name (for example, #r "AssemblyName"):1
>
> - Newtonsoft.Json
> - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
> - Microsoft.ServiceBus
> - Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers
> - Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Common
> - Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at an example that is an HTTP triggered functions (your webhook) and then writes to the service bus. Quick note: In their example, they write the function's return value as a message into service bus, you probably want to use an output binding:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
[return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
    return input.Text;
}
```

Comment: Return value is an output binding

Comment: do you know what I need to include in order to run this? I tried this example but as I said I can't include Microsoft.Azure.xxxx it gives me a bunch of errors

Comment: I got it compiling but it's giving me an error saying it's missing trigger "req", I'm assuming it needs a req param when using a http azure function. Is there a complete working example that I could refer to?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for Http trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook